# Cartier operator and logarithmic differentials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$, let $C$ be a curve over $k$ and let $\omega$ be a meromorphic differential form on $C$. If $\omega$ gets mapped to itself by the Cartier operator, does it follow that $\omega$ is of the form $df/f$, for some meromorphic function $f$ on $C$?

Obviously the converse is true: every logarithmic differential form $df/f$ gets mapped to itself by the Cartier operator.

Comment: Yes, this is true (of course, you want moreover $\omega$ closed). There is a proof in [this talk](http://www.numdam.org/article/SCC_1958-1959__4__A6_0.pdf) by Seshadri at the Chevalley seminar.

Comment: @abx Thank you for your answer!